# How can I add a string variable in the middle of another string?

Tags: c, string

I have a c program as below:

```
char* data1 = "test";//Here i have given some dummy value, the value will be evaluated in runtime
char* variable1 = "<Method name=\"data1\">";
```

The problem i am facing with this code is, instead of `data1`'s value `data1` variable name it self is getting stored for `variable1`. So i want to know here in the place of variable **`data1`** (as available in line 2), how can i get **test** which is its value during execution.

Expected result for `variable1`: `<Method name="test">`

Actual result i expect for `variable1`: `<Method name="data1">`

In java i use a "+" operator, i am struggling for the implementation in C.

Comment: Calculate the new size, allocate memory, copy the 1st part from what you have, concatenate the new part, concatenate the 2nd part of what you have,

Comment: Yes but is there any operator in c like i mention in java using which i can do it in one step rather going for 3 steps?

Comment: From the code you show I doubt this: "*Actual result: `variable1 = <Method name="data1">`*"

Comment: You want to read on the `str*()` family of functions in general, and how in C the missing data type "string" is emulated in particular.

Comment: it prints "<Method name="data1">" for variable 1. # Question edited

Comment: This "*`char* variable1 = "<Method name="data1">";`*" won't compile, at least not with the given definition of `data1`.

Comment: you mean i missed the escape characters

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114821/discussion-between-sanjit-kumar-mishra-and-alk).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `sprintf` or `snprintf` functions and `%s` placeholder, as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    char* data1 = "test";//Here i have given some dummy value, the value will be evaluated in runtime
    char* variable1 = "<Method name=\"%s\">";

    char result[500];

    sprintf(result, variable1, data1);

    snprintf(result, 500, variable1, data1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to print the output (value of variable 1)

Comment: `sprintf` don't prints the output, it just saves the built string it into `result` variable

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about variable declaration you can use string concatenation macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STRCAT(a, b, c) a b c

#define STR1 "test"

char* data1 = STR1;
char* variable1 = STRCAT("<Method name=\"", STR1, "\">" );

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n", variable1);
}
```

If you waht to build it runtime you can use, as already suggested [snprintf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm>):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* data1 = "test";
    char* variable1 = "<Method name=\"%s\">";
    char output[strlen(data1)+strlen(variable1)-1];

    snprintf(output, sizeof(output), variable1, data1 );

    printf("%s\n", output);
}
```

As you can see the resulting size of output array is calculated as:

- `strlen(data1) = 4`
- `strlen(variable1) = 18`

We have to remove `2` chars from `variable1` length due to format `"%s"` and add `1 byte` for null terminator because of `strlen` computes the length of a C-string but not including the terminating null character.

As pointer out by @alk [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) could not be supported by your compiler, So, Last example can be using [malloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* data1 = "test";
    char* variable1 = "<Method name=\"%s\">";
    size_t output_size = strlen(data1)+strlen(variable1)-1;

    char *output = malloc(output_size);

    if (output != NULL)
    {
        snprintf(output, output_size, variable1, data1 );

        printf("%s\n", output);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "malloc error");
    }

    free(output);
}
```

As you can see a memory is allocated dynamically and you must check that the required amount of byte were allocated successfully (pointer != NULL) and free the memory before exit. Because of [c](/questions/tagged/c) has not garbage collector, as java have.

Comment: You might like to add that `-1` in fact is `-2+1`. ;-) And as well add a comment on where those Magic Numbers come from.

Comment: Also the 2nd snippet uses a VLA, Support for VLAs is not mandatory with C11 any more and had not been around before C99.

Comment: @alk Comment: 1 I was editing. Comment 2 I added something to answer. :)